# Flickering Job details

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently noticed some flickering in a Job proposal:

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/292831/java-web-developer-m-f-d-medpex-versandapotheke

Comment: Seems to work fine on Firefox Nightly 89.0a1 desktop.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 89.0 version with Windows 10. Looks like you are using chrome as well... so could you see if the bug is still there?